# python random.randint generate 0-100 on increments of 5

Tags: python, numpy, random

Is it possible to generate a random number with `random.randint` from 0-100 on increments of 5?

```
random.randint(0,100)
```

If its possible I need way to generate random integers from 0-100 but only with increments of 5.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what `random.randint` is here? The numpy tag suggests you perhaps meant to talk about [`numpy.random.randint()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) but that's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either use [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) which lets you pick a step value:

```
random.randrange(0, 101, 5)
```

or just generate a number between `0` and `20` and multiply that number by 5:

```
random.randint(0, 20) * 5
```

I'm assuming here that `100` is a valid result. If `100` should not be generated, use `random.randrange(0, 100, 5)` or `random.randint(0, 19) * 5`.

If you wanted to generate a `numpy` array of such numbers using the [`numpy.random.randint()` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) (instead of the [standard library `random` module version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)), just use

```
np.random.randint(0, 20, size=expected_size) * 5
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code will generate random integer between 0 to 100

```
    import numpy as np
    random.choice(np.arange(0,101,5))
```